# Can someone explain the config settings for OrgDBOrgSettings utility?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to use the [OrgDBOrgSettings tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691237) to access an online CRM 2011 Org. I downloaded it and modified the config, per instructions, using the sample online config provided as a guide. It's not clear what some settings should be and I ended up with the settings below. When I run the app, it gets as far as asking for a password and then tells me the highly informative statement that **Error occurred in OrgDBOrgSettings and the error details are The parameter is incorrect.**

There doesn't seem to be any info other than the above link available. Anyone got any suggestions?

```
<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_CrmService_CrmService" serializeAs="String">
<!--- Please change CrmServer to your Crm Server Name -->
<value>https://crm.dynamics.com/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx</value>
</setting>

<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_CrmDiscoveryService_CrmDiscoveryService" serializeAs="String">
<!--- Please change CrmServer to your Crm Server Name -->
<value>https://dev.crm.dynamics.com/XrmServices/2011/Discovery.svc</value>
</setting>

<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_SKU" serializeAs="String">
<!--- Possible values here are Online/SPLA/OnPrem -->
<value>Online</value>
</setting>

<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_UserName" serializeAs="String">
<!--- Please change the value below to your email Id/User Name for Online / SPLA -->
<value>my crm login email</value>
</setting>

<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_Domain" serializeAs="String">
<value>DOMAIN</value>
</setting>

<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_OrgServiceUri" serializeAs="String">
<value>https://dev.api.crm.dynamics.com/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc</value>
</setting>

<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_RegistrationEndPointUri" serializeAs="String">
<value>https://login.live.com/ppsecure/DeviceAddCredential.srf</value>
</setting>

<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_Partner" serializeAs="String">
<!--- This is applicable only for Online -->
<value>Crm.Dynamics.com</value>
</setting>

<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_Environment" serializeAs="String">
<!--- This is applicable only for Online -->
<value></value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work with the help of MS support. I'll post the config below that worked for me. Note that I am accessing an online version of CRM. Also, make sure you delete any files in the LiveDeviceID folder as the app seems to get confused when there is an existing entry there. For me that directory was under `users/<me>`. Also note that allegedly you have to logon with a CRM admin account. Also note that I have only tested this with a hotmail email.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <OrgDBOrgSettingsTool.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_CrmService_CrmService" serializeAs="String">
        <!--- Please change CrmServer to your Crm Server Name -->
        <value>http://CrmServer/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_CrmDiscoveryService_CrmDiscoveryService"
          serializeAs="String">
        <!--- Please change CrmServer to your Crm Server Name -->
        <value>https://dev.crm.dynamics.com/XrmServices/2011/Discovery.svc</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_SKU" serializeAs="String">
        <!--- Possible values here are Online/SPLA/OnPrem -->
        <value>Online</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_UserName" serializeAs="String">
        <!--- Please change the value below to your admin email Id/User Name for Online / SPLA -->
        <value>your_crm_admin_email></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_Domain" serializeAs="String">
        <value>crmdom</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_OrgServiceUri" serializeAs="String">
        <value>https://your_org_name.crm.dynamics.com/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_RegistrationEndPointUri" serializeAs="String">
        <value>https://login.live.com/ppsecure/DeviceAddCredential.srf</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_Partner" serializeAs="String">
        <!--- This is applicable only for Online -->
        <value>Crm.Dynamics.com</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_Environment" serializeAs="String">
        <!--- This is applicable only for Online -->
        <value>INT</value>
      </setting>
    </OrgDBOrgSettingsTool.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CRM server name node looks wrong to me. Try this:

```
<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_CrmService_CrmService" serializeAs="String">
  <value>http://yourorgname.api.crm.dynamics.com/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx</value>
</setting>
```

Answer (score 0):

(I know this question is old but there do not seem to be any good references for this, so I thought I would add some useful info here)

Some things to check:

If you are using CRM Online outside USA then you need to replace crm.dynamics.com with crm4.dynamics.com (for EMEA) or crm5.dynamics.com (APAC) throughout

CRM server name should by "myorg.crm...." eg

```
<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_CrmService_CrmService" serializeAs="String">
<!--- Please change CrmServer to your Crm Server Name -->
<value>https://YOURORG.crm.dynamics.com/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx</value>
</setting>
```

OrgService URI needs the api bit but again should be myorg. :

```
<setting name="OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_OrgServiceUri" serializeAs="String">
<value>https://YOURORG.api.crm.dynamics.com/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc</value>
</setting>
```